# Remove bottom right "follow" bar from sophisticated business theme

Tags: wordpress, theme, administration, follow

[image: bottom right button]

I haven't figured out how to remove this button from a fresh wordpress site hosted on wordpress.com

I'm hoping to find a setting to turn it off, because when I'm in the editor, I don't see it but it's showing up when I'm not logged in.